Saving changes to .scss and .js project files doesn't trigger Parcel's HMR
I'm running a simple test project to learn bundling with Parcel.
OS: Windows 11
Environment: WSL2
Text editor: VS Code
Browser: Google Chrome
This is the file structure I'm running with:
/mnt/d/dev/test
├── .parcel-cache
├── .prettierrc
├── dist
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── img
    ├── js
    │   └── controller.js
    ├── sass
    │   └── styles.scss


Here's index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="module" src="./src/js/controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/sass/styles.scss" />
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="__container">
      <p>We're testing parcel with sass</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


I ran the following commands in the VS Code terminal:
$ npm init -y
$ npm install parcel sass --save-dev

After dependencies were downloaded, I added the following scripts to the newly generated package.json file:
"start": "parcel index.html",
"build": "parcel build index.html"

package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.12.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.6"
  }
}


And here are the contents of styles.scss:
// Define variables for colors
$royal-blue: #4169e1;

.__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.__container p {
  color: $royal-blue;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


I run the localhost server with the following command in terminal:
$ npm run start

If I change the scss file, e.g. changing the font-size: 2rem to 4rem, I expect to see this change reflected in the VS Code terminal (e.g. Built in 1.6x), as well as the web-page refreshing in the browser. This doesn't happen. For this to work, I have to save either index.html or package.json. Otherwise, what i understand to be the HMR feature of Parcel doesn't work.
Following suggestions seen online, I have tried the following:

Ensured the script and style files are correctly referenced in the head of index.html;

Removed the .parcel-cache directory using $ rm -rf .parcel-cache in VS Code terminal, followed by running $ npm start.


Expected behavior: saving a small change in the styles.scss file should trigger a build operation, observable in the VS Code terminal, and a refresh of the web-page running onn local-host:1234.
Results: The page isn't rebuilt unless saving index.html or package.json.
